# References about tropical cluster algebras and tropical Laurent phenomenon

Tags: cluster-algebras

Are there some references about tropical cluster algebras and tropical Laurent phenomenon? I searched on Google but only found one paper: [Tropical Plucker functions and their bases](http://mathecon.cemi.rssi.ru/danilov/files/TP-bases.pdf)
.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

Let me suggest Lauren Williams and my paper as a starting point:

*David Speyer and Lauren Williams*, MR 2164397 [**The tropical totally positive Grassmannian**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10801-005-2513-3), *J. Algebraic Combin.* **22** (2005), no. 2, 189--210.

It's earlier than a lot of the other references mentioned, so it isn't as sophisticated but, for that reason, it is a lot more concrete.

Answer (score 4):

There are certainly things related to tropical cluster algebras associated to surfaces.  See Fomin, Shapiro, Thurston, https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0608367, especially section 9.5, and the sequel by Fomin and Thurston, https://arxiv.org/abs/1210.5569, sections 14 and 15.

There is also work by Fock and Goncharov along similar lines, see for example https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0510312.  (Note that this is much more accessible than some of their work!)

Comment: thank you very much for the references. It seems that they didn't mention the tropical Laurent phenomenon in these papers?

Comment: I can believe that.